# Demo Google Accounts for App Testing?

Tags: openid, login-control, google-openid

I'm working on an openid login system for an app I'm building and I'm wondering if anyone has ever heard of a "dummy" Google Account for testing?

I have my own Google account that I've used, but I want to make sure it's working with different users.

So, I'm wondering if Google provides a few accounts for this purpose?

I'd rather not sign up my own "dummy" accounts, but it might be my only choice.

Thanks!
Troy

Comment: No there isn't!! Not sure but if you didn't find any you will see that I was correct! ;) But seriously I doubt that, go ahead and create some for yourself.

Comment: ha!  Thanks John.  I'll probably just create a bunch of "fake" accounts to make sure it's working properly.  Just hate to waste resources like that.